# Setting up MySQL Connection in JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: mysql, jboss7.x, openshift

For our capstone project in college we are to create a web application.  Our group chose to deploy our application to Openshift.com

I have successfully setup applications in tomcat to connect to MySQL but it seems that I am at a loss in this environment.  I have covered many how to guides but still unable to connect.

I have created the datasouce but not sure exactly where is should reside

```
<datasources> 
    <local-tx-datasource> 
        <jndi-name>MySqlDS</jndi-name> 
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jboss</connection-url> 
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class> 
        <user-name>user</user-name> 
        <password>password</password> 
    </local-tx-datasource> 
</datasources>
```

I am looking for a howto on setting up the connection to MySQL. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for how to use MySQL on openshift, check out this KB article, it should get you going: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1086-how-to-use-the-pre-configured-mysqlds-and-postgresqlds-data-sources-in-the-java

Comment: Thank you very much!  That was the direction I was looking for.